# Converting FLV files in Objective-C

Tags: cocoa, macos, video

So if I wanted to produce a bit of code to convert an flv file to really any other format in Cocoa/Objective-C, what would be the best way to go about it? I have been trying to avoid dependence on FFmpeg, due to their licensing rules and such, does anyone know of a good place to start with this?

Very appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way without external libraries or plugins.

Quicktime can do it.  Though it doesn't support FLV.  You would need to use a plugin like [perian](http://perian.org/).

Though I've only used Quicktime it for transcoding audio, not video, so I could be wrong.

Look at [QTKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTCocoaObjCKit/_index.html) as the Quicktime C api will be obsolete soon.

Also, you should be able to use FFMPEG or it's libraries in your app.  Lots of apps use it.  You just need to be careful about the licensing restrictions.

Comment: Hello, Can you describe what are the restrictions? and how "Lot's of apps use it"? Thanks